# How configure List Filter Webpart?

Tags: list, web-part, filter

I have  two list :

1. **Users**:

   **Fields**: username (AD users), region and city.
2. **Cities**:

   **Fields**: regions and cities

I would like to filter Cities list by current user's region.

I created List filter webpart, I can choose user manually and it filters well the "Cities" list.

How can I send default user value to webpart?

I have tried to use default user filter webpart and get default value from it, but it does not work.